# How to create dockerfile for c# mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, dockerfile

I am newbie in system managment.
Is there any tutorial that shows how to create a dockerfile with docker and virtual box for c# mvc application?
To pull existance application from docker server and then create dockerfile is done. I want to create dockerfile for my local mvc application in visual studio 2013.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is  designed for Linux, but using Mono or wine you may  succeed see for example http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/08/docker-c-sharp-scripted-build-in-6-minutes/

Comment: The link no longer works. :(